# How does the enumerate function work?

Tags: python, enumeration, enumerate

I am supposed to do the following:

> Define a function `my_enumerate(items)` that behaves in a similar way to the built-in `enumerate` function. It should return a list of pairs `(i, item)` where `item` is the `i`th item, with `0` origin, of the list `items` (see the examples below). Check the test cases for how the function should work. Your function must not call Python's in-built `enumerate` function.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> ans = my_enumerate([10, 20, 30])
> print(ans)
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30)]
> ```

Comment: If you're supposed to do it, why ask here?

Comment: What do you mean *"how does [it] work"*? Do you want to know [what it does](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)? [How it's implemented](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ec6c812fbc1f/Objects/enumobject.c), ...? This is as simple as `zip(range(len(items)), items)`.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Couldn't wrap my head around how to actually code it. I knew what the enumerate function did, and knew what I had to code but actually coding it was difficult.

Comment: You have to write something which doesn't work, then improve it. You'll do better if you write as much as you can then ask questions about the part you can't get to work.

Answer (score 3):

What does `enumerate` do? Try expressing it in English, and it may help you understand how to write the necessary code. If it doesn't then the practice of learning English language descriptions into code will be useful.

One way of describing `enumerate` is to say it iterates over each item in the list, and for each item in the input list it produces a pair of the item's index in the input list and the item.

So we know we need to iterate over the list:

```
for item in input_list:
    pass
```

And we need to keep track of the index of the current item.:

```
index = 0
for item in input_list:
    index += 1
```

Hmm, there's a better way of doing that:

```
for index in range(len(input_list)):
    pass
```

Now to produce the pairs:

```
for index in range(len(input_list)):
    pair = index, input_list[index]
```

You also need somewhere to store these pairs:

```
def my_enumerate(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for index in range(len(input_list)):
        pair = index, input_list[index]
        output_list.append(pair)
    return output_list
```

Are there other ways to write code that produces the same output? Yes. Is this the best way to write this function? Not by a long shot. What this exercise should help you with is turning your thoughts into code, as you gain more experience doing that then you can combine multiple steps at a time, and start using more complicated programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import count

def my_enumerate(values):
    return list(zip(count(), values))
```

Comment: `list()` is unnecessary (in Python 2).